# Get IP address of a website which can be provided to AWS security

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking

I have developed an application which is hosted on an iPaas provider. This application has to make a REST API call to a service which is running inside an AWS  EC2 instance.

Please note that the application is not pushed to AWS. In order to do so, I've to provide access to the cloud provider so that the REST call can be made successfully to the API residing in AWS. That means, in order to make a successful REST call, my application (hosted on some cloud) has to get permission from AWS (where a service is hosted and to which the application is making REST request). But AWS doesn't provide the option to enter the URL. How can we make this possible?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you not know the IP address of the AWS instance, or does it not accept requests from IPs that it doesn't recognize? Also, exactly what part of AWS are you using, i.e., EC2, S3, etc.?

Comment: I am using ec2. I dont know the IP address of server where my application is hosted

Comment: Have you tried running `ifconfig -a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look up the documentation of your Cloud Provider.
They for sure must have provided you with the public IP of the machine made available to you.

Another way of solving your problem could be by using the ping command. If you trying to ping the URL of your cloud provider, it will show you the IP address.
But here one issue you may encounter is, depending on your cloud providers size there could be more than one machines which may be providing the service
and it may happen that the IP provided by ping command and the IP of the machine where your app is pushed may be different and your purpose may not be fulfilled.
Here you may try to use the network masks (which you use while providing the access to any IP in AWS security groups)
Try providing access to a supernet.

Or you can also explore the usage of some standard tools like "tracert", "traceroute", "nslookup"

Comment: I did not understand the subnet part

Comment: If you look at the way you provide the IP addresses in the security settings of AWS, you will notice something like x.x.x.x/32. The 32 tells how many bits you wish to consider in the IP. By providing it as /16 or 8 you can allow more number of machines which are part of a bigger network. Try using x.x.x.x/8 and check if that works.

Comment: Now I understood

Comment: Glad I could help